# Proxy checker always raises exception

Tags: python, python-requests

So I wrote a quick script to try and figure out how to check proxies in python:

```
import requests

proxies = []

body = requests.get('https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol='
                    'http&timeout=1500&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=all').text
cut = body.split('\r\n')
cut.pop()

for i in cut:
  print('checking ', i)
  if i in proxies:
    print(i, ' is already in the pool')
  else:
    try:
        res = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json',
                           proxies={'http': runner, 'https': runner}, timeout=1.5)
        if res.status_code == 200:
          print('adding ', i, ' to the pool')
          proxies.append(i)
        else:
          print(i, ' is dead')
    except:
        print('error')
```

It does actually grab the proxies and split them, and remove the blank value at the end of the list, but when it comes to checking it just prints error.

This is what I mean:
[image: screenshot of errors]

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Avoid using bare `except:` clauses like that, they hide what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I suggest you to use

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception as myerr:
    print(myerr)
```

or use traceback

```
import traceback
try:
    # some code
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

when you want to catch an error.

Second, your code is throwing an error because in this line

```
res = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', proxies={'http': runner, 'https': runner}, timeout=1.5)
```

the variable `runner` is not defined.

I also suggest you to check the proxies directly using requests and not via third party services.

Comment: i just test them on an api which returns my ip